# mysqlbinlog failing with " ERROR 1032 (HY000) at line 48: Can't find record in `` " Error

Tags: mysql, restore, mysqldump, backup

I am facing some issue with PITR restore using mysqlbinlog . It is failing with the following error .

```
 # mysqlbinlog mysql-bin.000035 | mysql -u root -p db
 Enter password:
 ERROR 1032 (HY000) at line 48: Can't find record in 'dlfilerank'
```

`dlfilerank` is used by Liferay CMS App and the total records for this table keeps on changing when Liferay Portal is being accessed.

Following are the latest few binary log files generated by MySQL in my DB Server.

```
-rw-rw---- 1 mysql mysql 1073742407 Dec 27 18:26 /var/lib/mysql/mysql-bin.000033
-rw-rw---- 1 mysql mysql 1073742182 Feb  2 18:58 /var/lib/mysql/mysql-bin.000034
-rw-rw---- 1 mysql mysql        665 Feb  2 18:58 /var/lib/mysql/mysql-bin.index
-rw-rw---- 1 mysql mysql  422392027 Feb 18 15:50 /var/lib/mysql/mysql-bin.000035
```

From the above listing , we can see that the latest binary log (`mysql-bin.0000350`) was created around Feb 2,19:00 and all DB transactions from this timestamp onwards are being written to `mysql-bin.000035`

Now since latest binary log was created on  Feb 2, , so I am considering full backup taken using `mysqldump`on Feb 2. For full backup , we have an automated script using `mysqldump` which runs every midnight to take the backup.

So , to test restore for this setup , I am doing the  following steps:

1. Restore from full backup taken using `mysqldump` on  `Feb 2`
2. Next step , I execute mysqlbinlog generated on `Feb 2` for PITR restore but it is failing with the error mentioned in original description.

Kindly suggest how to resolve the issue ? Do I need to manually generate a new binary log file before taking full backup .

Answer (score 1):

## PROBLEM

You are starting from the wrong log. You should start with `mysql-bin.000034` not `mysql-bin.000035`

The timestamp on each binlog shows the last time a binlog event was written to it

- `mysql-bin.000033` was last written `Dec 27 18:26`
- `mysql-bin.000034` was last written `Feb  2 18:58`. That's 18 hrs 58 min after `Feb  2 00:00`
- `mysql-bin.000035` had to be created `Feb  2 18:58`

Given the timestamps mentioned, `mysql-bin.000034` is the log you need to start with.

## SOLUTION

You should collect the binlog events from `Feb  2 00:00`

Please run the following

```
MYCHANGES=ChangesSinceFeb2Backup.sql
BINLOGS="mysql-bin.000034 mysql-bin.000035"
cd /var/lib/mysql
mysqlbinlog --start_datetime="2014-02-02 00:00:00" ${BINLOGS} > ${MYCHANGES}
```

Restore the Feb 2 mysqldump Backup, then play all the events

```
mysql -u root -p db < ${MYCHANGES}
```

This will bring back everything up to `Feb 18 15:50`

If you want to do the PITR up to today at 12:45, you do this

```
MYCHANGES=ChangesSinceFeb2Backup.sql
cd /var/lib/mysql
mysqlbinlog --start_datetime="2014-02-02 00:00:00" --stop_datetime="2014-02-18 12:45:00" ${BINLOGS} > ${MYCHANGES}
```

## SUGGESTION

Note that `mysql-bin.000035` contains several days worth of binlog events.

Before you run the midnight backup, you should run

```
FLUSH BINARY LOGS;
```

That way, you can clearly identify what binary logs to use in PITR

## Give it a Try !!!

Comment: It is still failing for me . Now with the following error  # mysqlbinlog mysql-bin.000034 | mysql -u root -p asdb

ERROR 1062 (23000) at line 47: Duplicate entry '768522' for key 'PRIMARY'
The issue is not because of 'mysqlbinlog' problem but because of inconsistent data in 'dlfilerank' table as mentioned in original description . I will raise a separate question for this issue

Comment: Did you reload he Feb 2 backup before trying my solution ?

Comment: yeah...I reloaded Feb 2 backup before trying your solution